# Likert package barplot is adding some groups to the plot twice, how can I remove them -- what am I doing wrong?

Tags: ggplot2, axis-labels, likert

I am trying to plot the following Likert item:

```
    structure(list(`Likelihood of attending more frequently` = structure(c(4L, 
4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 
4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 
1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 
5L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 
2L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 4L), .Label = c("Highly unlikely", "Somewhat unlikely", 
"Neither likely nor unlikely", "Somewhat likely", "Highly likely"
), class = "factor"), Reason = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("Class times conflict with my schedule", 
"I am not interested in the content offered", "I don't have time", 
"I don't have transportation", "I don't know where to find information on classes, programs, and events", 
"Other", "There are not classes near me"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-180L), class = "data.frame")
```

When I check the factor levels of rhe group items it displays 7
, however, the likert.bar.plot has 9 groups as 2 are duplicated.

```
like<-likert(freq[, c(1), drop=FALSE], grouping = freq$Reason)
likert.bar.plot(like,wrap.grouping = 40)
```

I have checked to see if the text strings are different, but they are exactly the same.
Any idea what could be causing this?

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately your issue is not reproducible with the example data you provided. However, from the image you posted your duplicated groups are actually different, i.e. it looks as if the labels for some obs. include a line break. Hence, the groups are treated as different categories.

Comment: I could include the entire dataset if that helps, but the breaks were created when I used wrap.grouping

Comment: @stefan I have included the whole df. For some strange reason wrap.grouping only worked on non-duplicated groups.

Comment: Hm. Weird. This looks like a bug to me. I had a closer look at the plotting code. As far as I get it the issue is that for the bars the unwrapped group labels are used, while for the percentage labels the wrapped ones are used. Hence we end up with duplicated groups.

Comment: Interesting, I'll post the issue on github. It looks like @jbryer is pretty good about responding to bugs. Thanks for helping idenify the issue, even if we couldn't solve it.

Comment: Do that. And see the workaround I just added as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I already mentioned in my comment this looks like a bug to me. Both from the source code of `likert.bar.plot` and from the image it looks as if for the bars the unwrapped group labels are used, while for the percentage labels the wrapped ones are used. Hence we end up with duplicated groups.

However, as a workaround you could wrap the group labels manually before passing to likert. To make this work you also have to set the same width for the `wrap.grouping` argument:

```r
library(likert)

levels(freq$Reason) <- stringr::str_wrap(levels(freq$Reason), width = 40)
like <- likert(freq[, 1, drop = FALSE], grouping = freq$Reason)
likert.bar.plot(like, wrap.grouping = 40)
```

[image]

Comment: That definitely worked and is what I was trying to do with the axis lebel. Your workaround will be very useful going forward. Bug report has been filled out.